How to get unique search results from an array of nested objects?
I have a document with an array of objects that has a property with comma separated tags. Other documents can have identical toys.
  [
    {
      "documentId": 1,
      "toys": [
        {
          "id": "A",
          "tags": "foo, bar, baz"
        },
        {
          "id": "B",
          "tags": "test"
        },
        {
          "id": "C",
          "tags": "bar"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "documentId": 2,
      "toys": [
        {
          "id": "A",
          "tags": "foo, bar, baz"
        },
        {
          "id": "B",
          "tags": "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

I need a list of unique toy objects based on the user's search (in tags). Here is what I came up with, but this is unique for the entire index. Not quite what I need.
GET my-index/_search
{
  "size": "0",
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "toys",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "toys.tags.ngram": {
                  "analyzer": "standard",
                  "query": "bar",
                  "operator": "AND"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "toys.tags": {
                  "query": "bar"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_matches": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "toys"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top-result": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I would expect to get A and C back based on the search of "bar". Any ideas?

You could use the parent and sibling terms aggregations. Query text is in the include parameter of the parent terms aggregation. The search query results may have duplicates, but not the aggregation query results
Mapping
PUT /my-index
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "toys": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "tags": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fielddata": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The tags field must have the fielddata parameter with true. It needs for the terms aggregation
Your documents
PUT /my-index/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"documentId":1,"toys":[{"id":"A","tags":"foo, bar, baz"},{"id":"B","tags":"test"},{"id":"C","tags":"bar"}]}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"documentId":2,"toys":[{"id":"A","tags":"foo, bar, baz"},{"id":"B","tags":"test"}]}

Aggregation query
GET /my-index/_search?filter_path=aggregations.inside_toys.by_tag
{
    "aggs": {
        "inside_toys": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "toys"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "by_tag": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "toys.tags",
                        "include": "bar",
                        "size": 10
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "by_id": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "toys.id",
                                "size": 10
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "inside_toys" : {
      "by_tag" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "bar",
            "doc_count" : 3,
            "by_id" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "A",
                  "doc_count" : 2
                },
                {
                  "key" : "C",
                  "doc_count" : 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

